# replicating couchdb with drupal

Tags: services

I have a project where I would use DRUPAL as an internal facing administration system. May even be used as a Client facing solution.  But it would NOT be PUBLIC facing. My reason is that I want to use DRUPAL's roles, Authentication, and forms handling. 
The PUBLIC facing/ client end is something different.  These will be Mobile apps on iPHONE and ANDROID.  And there will be a lot of data.
My thought was that the master DB could be maintained in the DRUPAL system as it would be under minimal Authenticated load.  But CRON jobs would fire at random times to take a snap shot of data and post it the couchDB system.
I am choosing couchDB because I am already comfortable with its replication including replication to mobile devices.
My DRUPAL question is, how do a create the JSON file and post it to a couchDB system?

SOme thoughts...
1... Write a module that fires a procedure that will take a snap shot of the db and post it to the couch system.  This could also post static JSON files to an FTP server, that could be synched to mobile devices.  But this can be overwhelming for the hosting computer.  Can I get some sample code or suggestions please.

2... Use DRUPAL services. Write Node.js ( or what ever my taste is )   that will create a JSON file, and post it to the couchDB system.  Or create static files.  I personally like this idea as I can host the Node.js on a separate system.

3... is there another way?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.